# Basic Web crawler giving no output

Tags: python-3.x

So, I was making this web crawler on python 3 but it has no impact or output. I've tried several things,but nothing did worked.but if I don't put    ***{'class': 'product-thumb '}***   then it works and give me all the links on the page.

here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider(maxpage):
page=1
while page <= maxpage:
    url = 'https://www.startech.com.bd/product/search?&search=headphone&category_id=0&page=' + str(page)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'product-thumb '}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
    page += 1



spider(5)
```

Comment: You have an extra space in "product thumb ". Try `soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'product-thumb'}`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for an `a` tag with class name of `product-thumb` but in actuality, on the web page, the class `product-thumb` is of type `div`. If you change your code to the following, you should see results :

```
def spider():
   url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/'
   source_code = requests.get(url)
   text = source_code.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

   divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lead-story'})

   for div in divs:
      print('text : {}'.format(div.text))
```

Comment: its same,I did tried but sadly there was no output.

Comment: I'm away from my machine right now so can't debug it at the moment. Have you tried printing the full `soup` value out to see the output? Maybe the soup text is not what you're thinking it should be

Comment: Actually,I was learning python and I did exactly what they did in the video.the only deference was the url and the class. somehow It worked for them but not for me :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to connect with the website in your example. I've changed my answer to a different website to show the code is working for crawling. Maybe you could possibly follow the code I've given and use it against a different website?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'product-thumb '}):
>     href = link.get('href')
> ```

`<div>` elements are not links, and while you can assign them to a variable named `link` they will not have `href` attributes.

The link is the grandchild of the `product-thumb` div.

I assume you can do `link.find('a')` but I haven't used BeautifulSoup in about a decade.

Comment: I tried with product name also.but every time
"none
none
none"
came in the answer

here's the inspect element results

<h4 class="product-name">
                                    <a href="https://www.startech.com.bd/asus-cerberus-v2-gaming-headphone">Asus Cerberus V2 3.5mm gaming Headphone</a>
                                </h4>